# Mongoose Schema show the array if a friendId exist in Users Model schema

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have created a user which has its login data and into it is has some arrays including friends, groups, pages and other stuff.
But I am stucked when I want see who has sent me a friend request.
So I have am trying to create the friend request/response as in Facebook.
My logic it is for the moment when I send you a friend request I add to my array of friends and then with post request I can see at which users is my ID added and it has the status Pending.
For the moment I have tried something but I am getting empty array as response.
My code is below.

User model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const userDataScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    phone: {
        number: String,
        countryCode: String,
        dialCode: String,
        e164Number: String,
        internationalNumber: String,
        nationalNumber: String
    },
    gender: Number,
    birthday_day: String,
    birthday_month: String,
    birthday_year: String,
    friends: [{
        _id: false,
        friendId: String,
        createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        status: Number,
    }
    ]
},
    { autoIndex: false });
userDataScheme.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: 'Email already in use.' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userDataScheme);
```

user.service.js backend

```
const User = require("../models/user");
async function findYourPendingContact({friendId}) {
    return await User.find({friends: friendId});
}

module.exports = {
    findYourPendingContact
}
```

routes.js

```
routes.post("/user-friends", UserController.findYourContacts);
```

This is the Controller.

```
const userService = require("../service/user.service");
async findYourContacts(req, res, next) {
    let friendId = req.body.friendId;
    userService.findYourPendingContact({friendId: friendId})
    .then(friends => res.json(friends))
    .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

So seems my Database Json.
The user that added me as friend.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("620bfd2d860fd314fc538df3"),
    "firstName" : "Max",
    "email" : "maxmuster@outlook.de",
    "lastName" : "Muster",
    "password" : "$2b$10$D8l15CTZHbp/rcApqXpwT.KUbHAg0hBYp0h1qounnKFW.plDO9wKe",
    "phone" : {
        "number" : "1234566",
        "countryCode" : "DE",
        "dialCode" : "+49",
        "e164Number" : "+491234566",
        "internationalNumber" : "+49 1234566",
        "nationalNumber" : "1234566"
    },
    "gender" : 1,
    "birthday_day" : "13",
    "birthday_month" : "8",
    "birthday_year" : "1998",
    "friends" : [
        {
            "friendId" : "6204605617d5fcc3c179f3cc", // this here is my ID
            "status" : 0,
            "createdDate" : {
                "$date" : 1644971031461
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Here are my Data on backend

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6204605617d5fcc3c179f3cc"),
    "firstName" : "Test",
    "email" : "test.test@outlook.com",
    "lastName" : "Test",
    "password" : "$2b$10$koGb0fIcdWvq2ugGQXF7.OOmoof1QCH8IKQtoMGl9MHSJuu5Xumd6",
    "phone" : {
        "number" : "01234567",
        "countryCode" : "DE",
        "dialCode" : "+49",
        "e164Number" : "+4901234567",
        "internationalNumber" : "+49 01234567",
        "nationalNumber" : "01234567"
    },
    "gender" : 0,
    "birthday_day" : "8",
    "birthday_month" : "5",
    "birthday_year" : "1994",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now this is the part of my frontend when I login.

```
 public getUserFriends(userId): Observable<any> {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/user-friends`
    return this.http.post(api, JSON.stringify({friendId: userId}), this.httpOptions).pipe(
      map((response: User) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
      },
      (err) => {
        throw err;
      })
    )
  }
```

user.helper.ts

```
  showPendingFriends(authId): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable<any>(observer => {
      this.userService.getUserFriends({friendId: authId}).subscribe(response => {
        observer.next(response);
      })
    })
  }
```

components.ts

```
 this.userHelper.showPendingFriends(this.authService.userID).subscribe(res => console.log(res)); //this.authService.userID is my ID actually 6204605617d5fcc3c179f3cc or it can be any user ID
```